# Trying to Webscrape a Dynamic Website to Grab Drop Down Items

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to web-scrapping and what I am trying to do is print out all the bus routes from the drop down list from the following website: https://tmweb.pacebus.com/TMWebWatch/LiveDepartureTimes
I understand that this is a dynamic website so I decided to install selenium and use it alongside BeautifulSoup.

The following is my attempt to print out each element in the route drop down:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

pace_bus_url = 'https://tmweb.pacebus.com/TMWebWatch/LiveDepartureTimes'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(pace_bus_url)

page_source = driver.page_source
driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')

stops = soup.find_all(class_='active-result')
for stop in stops:
    print(stop.text.strip())

now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print(current_time)`
```

I made sure to also install chrome webdrivers through pip on pycharm terminal. When I run the program the only thing that gets printed is the current time but none of the routes from the drop down.

Comment: Those drop downs won't click themselves. You have to tell selenium to choose a route, then a direction, and finally a stop. Only then you'll get something back.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How would I have Selenium choose a route, direction, and stop?

Answer (score -1):

You can learn to use the Network Tab in DevTools, it shows all the requests your browser makes.

To speed things up, you can "Copy as fetch" which gives you javascript code - but it's easy enough to modify to python.

[image]

In this particular case, the only needed header is the `content-type`.

The `routeID` and `stopID` values we're using come from the previous `getRoutes` and `getStops` requests you can see in the screenshot which you can also replicate.

Python code to fetch the stop times:

```
import requests

r = requests.post(
   url = "https://tmweb.pacebus.com/TMWebWatch/Arrivals.aspx/getStopTimes",   
   headers = {"content-type": "application/json;\tcharset=UTF-8"},
   data = "{routeID: 293,\tdirectionID: 2,\tstopID:\t21906,\ttpID:\t0, useArrivalTimes:\tfalse}"
)
```

We can use [`r.json()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) to turn the JSON string into a python structure:

```
>>> r.json()
{'d': {'errorMessage': None,
  'showArrivals': False,
  'showStopNumber': False,
  'showScheduled': True,
  'showDestination': False,
  'updateTime': '5:27',
  'updatePeriod': 'pm',
  'routeStops': [{'routeID': 293,
    'stops': [{'directionID': 2,
      'stopID': 21906,
      'timePointID': 0,
      'sameDestination': False,
      'crossings': [{'cancelled': True,
        'schedTime': '5:35',
        'schedPeriod': 'pm',
        'predTime': None,
        'predPeriod': None,
        'countdown': None,
        'destination': None},
       {'cancelled': False,
        'schedTime': '5:50',
        'schedPeriod': 'pm',
        'predTime': '5:50',
        'predPeriod': 'pm',
        'countdown': None,
        'destination': None},
       {'cancelled': False,
        'schedTime': '6:05',
        'schedPeriod': 'pm',
        'predTime': '6:05',
        'predPeriod': 'pm',
        'countdown': None,
        'destination': None}]}]}]}}
```

It's essentially shorthand for: `json.loads(r.content)`

Comment: would I include the r.json() code within my python file, or would I create a new file? Also the second screenshot of code is that the javascript code from when you used "Copy as Fetch"

Comment: @Keegan `r` is the return value from `requests.get`, i.e. the response. The data being received is in JSON format and `r.json()` parses the JSON and turns it into a python structure. It contains the data in the webpage e.g. `schedTime`, `predTime`.

Comment: Would I be able to send the route and direction I want with the json approach, or do I have to pick the route and direction from the website first?

Comment: @Keegan I just showed a code example for the final `getStopTimes` request. If you look at the first `getRoutes` request - it returns the route names and their IDs. When you pick a route+direction in your browser it sends the `routeID`+`directionID` in the `getStops` request - which returns each `stopID`. These IDs are then sent to `getStopTimes` to get the times (the `data=` line in the code example).